# Post from Javascript to PHP within one file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have one php file called senttest.php. What I am trying to do is send a variable from php to javascript in order to run it through a sentiment analysis tool and then post it back to php within the same file. I can get everything working as necessary except the post back to php which comes up empty when I echo it. Any ideas or something obvious that I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
    <?php

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>




    <?php

     $full = 'Congratulations to our great military men and women for 
     representing the United States, and the world, so well in the Syria 
     attack.';
     ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">var r1 = "<?= $full ?>";
     var returntext = "";</script>
     <script src="sentiment/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
     url: 'senttest.php', //This is the current doc
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
     data: ({returned: returntext}),
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     }
     });
      document.write(returntext);

     document.write('done with send');


    </script>


<?php

$jsongrab = $_POST['returned'];



$json = json_decode($jsongrab, true);
?>
<p><?php echo $jsongrab ?></p>
<p><?php echo $json['comparative']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make sure you call the ajax after "returntext" is set by your sentiment-bundle.js

Comment: Is there a way in javascript I can wrap it in a function and call it automatically after, without a button press? Thanks!

Comment: yes, wait ill write an answer...

Answer (score 0):

This wont work the way it is right now.
A AJAX call is not suited for this since it will not display the fetched HTML. What you want is a redirect with post parameters.
Use Rakesh Pai's snippet for that:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Then call `post('senttest.php',{returned:returntext},'POST')` when returntext is set.

Comment: Just to clarify, my end goal is not to show the fetched html that was just how I was checking whether or not the variable was there.